# How do I convert an Adobe Illustrator Path to a Google Maps Polygon? (v3 API)

Tags: google-maps, adobe-illustrator

I have an illustrator file and I want to convert the numerous illustrator paths to Google maps polygons. I have done a number of searches through Google and this site, and there doesn't appear to be anything up-to-date on this topic.

I currently have a the illustrator file cut up with map-tiler and the zoom in and zoom out is working fine. I also center the map at coordinates (0.0,0.0). I know this coordinate is in the middle of the ocean, but I am not using the Google Maps library to give people directions. I just want to use it as a tool to display a custom map that is generated in Adobe Illustrator.

Any information would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Avenza MAPublisher is built for this task.

http://www.avenza.com/mapublisher

With MAPublisher you can export Illustrator polygons to KML which should be directly importable into Google maps.

(Disclosure, I work for Avenza)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried MAPublisher but haven't been able to figure out the process of getting exported properly to generate the Google Map polygons. Is this documented at all the exact process to export an AI file to a KML file with Google Map polygons?